# lightning-input-rich-text is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

I tried to use the lightning-input-rich-text in a sample component as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation
But unfortunately I cannot get it working. Not in webcomponents.dev, it shows the following error:
[image: Error on webcomponents.dev]

And also not on lwc playground. It shows the following error.
[image]

Here is the code of the LWC:

```
<template>
        <lightning-input-rich-text
        value={myVal}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
</template>
```

And this is the code of the controller:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
      get myVal() {
        return '**Hello!**';
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: **I would suggest trying it in a Salesforce org**, it looks like rich text has a dependency on quill.js and Salesforce knows that which is the reason most other components have an example but not the rich text one. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was simply not working in a Playground.